# How to create speedometer in D3JS?

Tags: d3.js

I am new to D3.Js i have to create a speedometer like

https://forums.databricks.com/storage/attachments/993-capture.png

[image]

so far i am able to create half circle design but not able to create same   indicator and that overlapping of indicator on arc.
how to achieve that?

My code is:

```
    var svg = d3.select("#speedometer")
            .append("svg:svg")
            .attr("width", 400)
            .attr("height", 400);


    var gauge = iopctrl.arcslider()
            .radius(120)
            .events(false)
            .indicator(iopctrl.defaultGaugeIndicator);
    gauge.axis().orient("in")
            .normalize(true)
            .ticks(10)
            .tickSubdivide(0)
            .tickSize(10, 8, 10).tickValues([20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90])
            .tickPadding(3)
            .scale(d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([10, 100])
                    .range([-Math.PI / 2, Math.PI / 2]));    

    svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "gauge")
            .call(gauge);


    gauge.value(76);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many example available for speedometer in d3.js.

please have a look

[speedometer](http://bl.ocks.org/metormote/6392996)

[d3 gauge](http://bl.ocks.org/msqr/3202712)